# JFormattedTextField : isEditValid() returns false with negative numbers.....sometimes

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

A table is defined with a custom Cell Editor which uses a JFormattedTextField.

The isEditValid() routine of the JFormattedTextField will be used to determine whether addition processing will take place so its important for it to return the correct value.

The issue is isEditValid() returns true at times and other times it returns false using the same negative value. The only difference is the version of the Java.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

class SimpleTest extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private String[] columnNames=new String[3];
    private String[][] dataValues=new String[3][3];

    public SimpleTest()
    {
        setTitle("JTable Cell Validation");
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        topPanel=new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);
        columnNames=new String[] {"Name" ,"Value"};
        dataValues=new String[][] {  {"DummyField ","0"} };
        
        TableModel  model=new myTableModel();
        table=new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);
        
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new MyCustomerEditor());

        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);
        topPanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
    }
    
    public class myTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
    {
        myTableModel()
        {
            super(dataValues,columnNames);
        }
    
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int cols)
        {
            if (cols == 0)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      SimpleTest x=new SimpleTest();
      x.setVisible(true);
    }  

    
    public class MyCustomerEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        int attrLength;
        
        public MyCustomerEditor() 
        {
            super(new JFormattedTextField());
            System.out.println("Inside the editor.");
            final NumberFormat integerFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
            integerFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
            integerFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
            integerFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);

            final NumberFormatter intFormatter = new NumberFormatter(integerFormat);
            intFormatter.setOverwriteMode(false);

            final JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = (JFormattedTextField) getComponent();
            formattedTextField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(intFormatter));
            formattedTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            formattedTextField.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.PERSIST);
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing()
        {
            System.out.println("Stopped editing");
            if (processData())
            {
                return false;
            }

            return super.stopCellEditing();
        }   
        
        boolean processData()
        {
            final JFormattedTextField textField = (JFormattedTextField) super.getComponent();
            final Object o = super.getCellEditorValue();
            final String integer = o.toString();

            System.out.println("Processing Integer value : " + integer);                    
            System.out.println("     textField.getText() : " + textField.getText()); 
            System.out.println("     textField.isEditValid() : " + textField.isEditValid());    
    
            return true;
        }   
    }
}
```

When it works, the JTable appears.

[image]

Double click the Value field to enter edit mode and enter -1 then press the Enter key.

[image]

The output generated.

[image]

When it does NOT work, here is the output generated.
Oh, also, the Enter key does not work. You will need to click off the field for output to generate.

[image]

Returns FALSE with Corretto Version 11

Returns TRUE with Oracle Version 1.8

Does anyone know of any issues with 11.0.10 or have any idea what may be generating the different results?

Edited to add:

The 3 different versions are installed on 3 different machines. Could a locale be a factor in the behavior and not the Java version?

Edited again to add:

This appears to be a locale issue. After passing in locale values via the -D option when executing, I can see the issue work and fail on the same machine simply by changing the value.

The new question is how to address something like this?

Is there another call other than isEditValid() that could be used and that won't be affected by a locale?

Answer (score 1):

You aren’t properly ending a cell edit, because you are not allowing the DefaultCellEditor’s `stopCellEditing` method to run:

```
@Override
public boolean stopCellEditing()
{
    System.out.println("Stopped editing");
    if (processData())
    {
        // processData() always returns true, so we always return here,
        // and super.stopCellEditing() is never called.
        return false;
    }

    return super.stopCellEditing();
}
```

JTable *needs* a proper implementation of stopCellEditing.  By preventing that method from doing anything, you are breaking the table.

The solution is to make sure super.stopCellEditing() always runs:

```
@Override
public boolean stopCellEditing()
{
    System.out.println("Stopped editing");
    boolean stop = super.stopCellEditing();

    processData();

    return stop;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code correction, but after making the change, it still doesn't work with the 1 locale setting. Debugging further and it appears to be failing with the JFormattedTextField object within the stringToValue() call. Its encountering a ParseException.   Further testing shows it actually fails with Corretto 11 but works with the Oracle 1.8 JDK.

Comment: @UnhandledException All Swing method and constructors need to run in the AWT event dispatch thread.  Change your main method to `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new SimpleTest().setVisible(true));`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/ for details.  Using Swing in the wrong thread leads to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Made the change but still no difference. Using the System.setproperties command to change user.country, user.language and user.language.format within the provided sample is when the issue arises.

Comment: `NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance()` will return a number format for the current locale.  If your computer is set to use a language and region which does not normally use ASCII digits (0 through 9) for numeric values, but you want your program to use ASCII digits anyway, use `NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)`.  (There actually are ways to create more complex Locale values, which use your native language for text while still using ASCII digits;  see [the documentation of Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) for details.)

Comment: thanks. Was not familiar with the NumberFormat object and its ability to accept a Locale. I was testing out the idea of saving off the Locale settings, changing it, then putting it back, but your suggestion is more direct and proper.